# High chart - localization of numbers

Tags: localization, highcharts

I high chart value like 1000000. How can I have it displayed with the proper commas in place like "10,000,000"

I write the regular expression like 
/(\d+)(\d{3})/

It  working fine for normal function..but when i use this one in High charts then it returns undefined

Comment: which chart ? some code please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat in formatters like axis label or tooltip. Additionally you have a possibility of using lang paramter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep

Answer (score 0):

you can use formatter availabele for labels,xAxis.labels, yAxis,labels, tooltip to format the numbers in your own way.

```
yAxis:{
   labels:{
       formatter: function(){
       }
   }
}
```

you can use the regular expression concept in that formatter function as well.

here is a example where i've applied my formatting on yAxis labels http://jsfiddle.net/2Jwsn/

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "[Format String](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/label-and-string-formatting)"

**For Tooltip:**

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: "Value: {point.y:,.0f}"
}
```

**For x/y labels:**

```
 yAxis: {        
            labels: {
                format: '{value:,.0f}'
            }
        }
```

**Labels:**

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format : '{y:,.0f}'
            }
        }
    }
```